# How to tag and add alt-text to a PDF without Adobe Acobat

Tags: pdf, accessibility

I am a student who has to create accessible PDFs by tagging and adding alt-text to all images. The way this is supposed to be done is by using Adobe Acrobat Pro. I do not have access to this without paying a lot, however.

So my question: is there a way to tag and add alt-text to images in a PDF without using Acrobat?

Comment: Try asking here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat Pro is not the only PDF editor - there exist many more,
where some are free and some are paid.

You will need to search for "PDF editor free" and try them out,
to see if they can do the requested operation.

One example (without recommendation) :
[Super PDF Editor Lite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-editor-free-lite/).

Comment: I looked at a few other PDF editors before asking this question and none of them had this functionality. Super PDF Editor Lite doesn't have it either, from what I can see. I guess my question is if anyone knows for sure of a way to do it. I don't particularly want to go download and try out hundreds of PDF editors.

Comment: You might ask the person who tasked you with this job to furnish you with a version of Adobe Acrobat Pro. Failing that, you could create the document in Word, where Alternative text is supported for images, and export as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Microsoft Word to add alt text to PDF files. Just follow the given steps and you are good to go.

1. Run Microsoft Word.
2. Open the PDF file using Microsoft Word.
3. Now click on the **Format Picture** option and enter your alt text.